# Bulk Insert the same row multiple (N) times

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Is there a way to BULK insert the same row into a table based on a variable N?

Basically:

```
INSERT INTO Table (FK_id, Somedate)
VALUES (3, GETDATE())
OVER 5000 ROWS
```

I know I can declare variables such as @InsertedRows and increment it within a while loop:

```
DECLARE @InsertedRows = 0;
WHILE (@InsertedRows < N)
  INSERT INTO Table (FK_id, Somedate)
  VALUES (3, GETDATE())

  @InsertedRows++
END WHILE
```

But that's multiple insert statements rather than 1 insert call, which I'd prefer. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find a recursive CTE is easy enough to do from memory and performs pretty well too.

```
DECLARE @limit int = 5000;

;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT n = 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT n + 1 FROM x WHERE n < @limit
)
INSERT dbo.tablename(FK_id, Somedate) 
SELECT 3, GETDATE() FROM x
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Comment: neat. I've never liked recursive CTEs. I try to avoid them in production code, as they always seem like something waiting to fail, but in this case it's a good use.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . I agree.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: which bit are you agreeing with?

Comment: @MitchWheat . . . A vote in favor of recursive CTEs.

Comment: in production code with (MAXRECURSION 0)? Strange choice.

Comment: @Mitch Why? Is there no other way to typo an infinite loop into a production system? (Or a disaster like `FROM L5, L5, L5`? Would you be happier with `MAXRECURSION 32767` and a disclaimer that if you need more than 32,767 rows you are S.O.L.? A recursive CTE has risks like any other, but it gets a job done.

Comment: FWIW "no recursive CTEs" is the same kind of blanket policy that has saddled half the world’s T-SQL codebase with `NOLOCK` on every single table reference.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I hardly think that's a fair comparison, and hoping you're not suggesting I would ever recommend using NOLOCK, because I wouldn't.

Comment: @Mitch That’s why I said “the same kind of blanket policy” and not “look, Mitch told everyone to use NOLOCK!”

Answer (score 2):

The really simple way in SSMS, is to do this:

```
INSERT INTO Table (FK_id, Somedate)
VALUES (3, GETDATE())
GO 5000
```

But it's still multiple inserts like that.

You can perform a single insert like so:

```
WITH
    L0 AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
    L1 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 A CROSS JOIN L0 B),
    L2 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 A CROSS JOIN L1 B),
    L3 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 A CROSS JOIN L2 B),
    L4 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 A CROSS JOIN L3 B),
    L5 AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 A CROSS JOIN L4 B),
    Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
INSERT INTO Table(FK_id, Somedate)
SELECT TOP (5000) 
FK_id, Somedate
FROM Nums 
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (3,  GETDATE())) t (FK_id, Somedate)
ORDER BY n
```